# AVG(COLUMN_SCORE) Not Getting Written To SQLite Database

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite, android-studio

I have created the following method to generate the average score for a series:

```
//Getting Series Averages From Game.COLUMN_SCORE
public String getSeriesAverage(String leagueId, String bowlerId)
{
    String total = "";
    Series series = new Series();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT AVG(" + Game.COLUMN_SCORE + ") FROM " + Game.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + Game.COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID + " = '" + leagueId + "'" + " AND " + Game.COLUMN_BOWLER_ID + " = '" + bowlerId + "'" + " GROUP BY " + Game.COLUMN_SERIES_ID /*+ " = '" + seriesId + "'"*/, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            total = cursor.getString(0);
            values.put(Series.COLUMN_SERIES_AVERAGE, total);
            database.update(Series.TABLE_NAME, values, Series.COLUMN_ID + "=" + series.getId(), null);

            Log.d("SERIES_AVERAGE - SQL","COLUMN_SERIES_AVERAGE = >>>>" + Series.COLUMN_SERIES_AVERAGE + "<<<<");
            Log.d("TOTAL - CURSOR VALUE","Total = >>>>" + total + "<<<<");
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        values.put(Series.COLUMN_SERIES_AVERAGE, total);

        database.update(Series.TABLE_NAME, values, Series.COLUMN_ID + "=" + series.getId(), null);
    }
    cursor.close();
    //Close Database Connection
    database.close();
    //Log.d("GET AVERAGE FROM SQL","Average = >>>>" + total + "<<<<");
    return total;
}
```

It seems to work and I can see the averages for each of the Series listed for an individual Bowler in Logcat:

```
07-26 14:50:15.158 25330-25330/ca.rvogl.tpbcui D/GETALLSERIES-SQL: SQL used = >>>>SELECT  * FROM Series WHERE league_id = '1' AND bowler_id = '1' ORDER BY timestamp DESC<<<<
07-26 14:50:15.167 25330-25330/ca.rvogl.tpbcui D/GETALLSERIESS-CNT: Number of rows retrieved = 3
07-26 14:50:15.175 25330-25330/ca.rvogl.tpbcui D/SERIES_AVERAGE - SQL: COLUMN_SERIES_AVERAGE = >>>>average<<<<
07-26 14:50:15.175 25330-25330/ca.rvogl.tpbcui D/AVERAGE OF FIRST SERIES: Average = >>>>207<<<<
07-26 14:50:15.175 25330-25330/ca.rvogl.tpbcui D/SERIES_AVERAGE - SQL: COLUMN_SERIES_AVERAGE = >>>>average<<<<
07-26 14:50:15.175 25330-25330/ca.rvogl.tpbcui D/AVERAGE OF FIRST SERIES: Average = >>>>111<<<<
07-26 14:50:15.175 25330-25330/ca.rvogl.tpbcui D/SERIES_AVERAGE - SQL: COLUMN_SERIES_AVERAGE = >>>>average<<<<
07-26 14:50:15.175 25330-25330/ca.rvogl.tpbcui D/AVERAGE OF FIRST SERIES: Average = >>>>300<<<<
07-26 14:50:15.175 25330-25330/ca.rvogl.tpbcui D/SERIES_AVERAGE - SQL: COLUMN_SERIES_AVERAGE = >>>>average<<<<
07-26 14:50:15.175 25330-25330/ca.rvogl.tpbcui D/AVERAGE OF FIRST SERIES: Average = >>>>1<<<<
07-26 14:50:15.175 25330-25330/ca.rvogl.tpbcui D/AVERAGE OF SERIES: Average = >>>>1<<<<
07-26 14:50:15.177 25330-25330/ca.rvogl.tpbcui D/GETALLSERIES-CNT: Number of elements in serieslist = 3
```

However as you can also see from the logcat the value is not being written to the database as shown here:

```
07-26 14:50:15.175 25330-25330/ca.rvogl.tpbcui D/AVERAGE OF FIRST SERIES: Average = >>>>300<<<<
07-26 14:50:15.175 25330-25330/ca.rvogl.tpbcui D/SERIES_AVERAGE - SQL: COLUMN_SERIES_AVERAGE = >>>>average<<<<
```

It is actually only displaying the name of the variable from Series Class.

Can anyone help me get these values written to the database.  I am not sure what I am doing incorrectly and any assistance would be appreciated.  If you need to see any additional code please let me know I will post it.

Structure of Series Table:

```
// Create table SQL query
    public static final String CREATE_TABLE =
            "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
                    + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                    + COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID + " TEXT,"
                    + COLUMN_BOWLER_ID + " TEXT,"
                    + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT,"
                    + COLUMN_SERIES_AVERAGE + " TEXT,"
                    + COLUMN_TIMESTAMP + " DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"
                    + ")";

    public Series() {
    }

    public Series(int id, String league_id, String bowler_id, String name, String average, String timestamp) {
        this.id = id;
        this.league_id = league_id;
        this.bowler_id = bowler_id;
        this.name = name;
        this.average = average;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
```

Logcat:

```
07-26 19:00:42.250 32441-32441/ca.rvogl.tpbcui D/GETALLSERIES-SQL: SQL used = >>>>SELECT  * FROM Series WHERE league_id = '1' AND bowler_id = '1' ORDER BY timestamp DESC<<<<
07-26 19:00:42.263 32441-32441/ca.rvogl.tpbcui D/GETALLSERIESS-CNT: Number of rows retrieved = 2
07-26 19:00:42.279 32441-32441/ca.rvogl.tpbcui D/SERIES_AVERAGE - SQL: COLUMN_SERIES_AVERAGE = >>>>null<<<<
07-26 19:00:42.279 32441-32441/ca.rvogl.tpbcui D/TOTAL - CURSOR VALUE: Total = >>>>111<<<<
07-26 19:00:42.281 32441-32441/ca.rvogl.tpbcui D/SERIES_AVERAGE - SQL: COLUMN_SERIES_AVERAGE = >>>>null<<<<
07-26 19:00:42.281 32441-32441/ca.rvogl.tpbcui D/TOTAL - CURSOR VALUE: Total = >>>>300<<<<
07-26 19:00:42.286 32441-32441/ca.rvogl.tpbcui D/GETALLSERIES-CNT: Number of elements in serieslist = 2
```

[image]

SeriesActivity

```
public class SeriesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SeriesAdapter mAdapter;
    private final List<Series> seriesList = new ArrayList<>();
    private TextView noSeriesView;

    private DatabaseHelper db;

    private TextView leagueId;
    private String savedLeagueId;
    private TextView bowlerId;
    private String savedBowlerId;
    private TextView seriesAverage;
    private String savedSeriesAverage;

    private static final String PREFS_NAME = "prefs";
    private static final String PREF_BLUE_THEME = "blue_theme";
    private static final String PREF_GREEN_THEME = "green_theme";
    private static final String PREF_ORANGE_THEME = "purple_theme";
    private static final String PREF_RED_THEME = "red_theme";
    private static final String PREF_YELLOW_THEME = "yellow_theme";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //Use Chosen Theme
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences( PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE );
        boolean useBlueTheme = preferences.getBoolean( PREF_BLUE_THEME, false );
        if (useBlueTheme) {
            setTheme( R.style.AppTheme_Blue_NoActionBar );
        }
        boolean useGreenTheme = preferences.getBoolean( PREF_GREEN_THEME, false );
        if (useGreenTheme) {
            setTheme( R.style.AppTheme_Green_NoActionBar );
        }
        boolean useOrangeTheme = preferences.getBoolean( PREF_ORANGE_THEME, false );
        if (useOrangeTheme) {
            setTheme( R.style.AppTheme_Orange_NoActionBar );
        }
        boolean useRedTheme = preferences.getBoolean( PREF_RED_THEME, false );
        if (useRedTheme) {
            setTheme( R.style.AppTheme_Red_NoActionBar );
        }
        boolean useYellowTheme = preferences.getBoolean( PREF_YELLOW_THEME, false );
        if (useYellowTheme) {
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Yellow_NoActionBar);
        }



        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_series);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar( toolbar );
        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String seriesLeagueId = String.valueOf( getIntent().getStringExtra( "seriesLeagueId" ) );
                String seriesBowlerId = String.valueOf( getIntent().getIntExtra( "seriesBowlerId", 2 ) );
                Intent intent=new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("seriesLeagueId",seriesLeagueId);
                intent.putExtra("seriesBowlerId",seriesBowlerId);
                setResult(1,intent);
                finish();//finishing activity
                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            }
            /*@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(SeriesActivity.this, BowlerActivity.class));
                finish();
            }*/
        });

        savedLeagueId = String.valueOf( getIntent().getStringExtra( "seriesLeagueId" ) );
        leagueId = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.tvLeagueId );
        savedBowlerId = String.valueOf( getIntent().getIntExtra( "seriesBowlerId", 2 ) );
        bowlerId = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.tvBowlerId );
        seriesAverage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSeriesAverage);

        CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout = findViewById( R.id.coordinator_layout );
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById( R.id.recycler_view );
        noSeriesView = findViewById( R.id.empty_series_view );

        db = new DatabaseHelper( this );


        seriesList.addAll( db.getAllSeries( savedLeagueId, savedBowlerId) );

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById( R.id.add_series_fab );
        fab.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showSeriesDialog( false, null, -1 );
            }
        } );

        mAdapter = new SeriesAdapter( this, seriesList );
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager( getApplicationContext() );
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager( mLayoutManager );
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator( new DefaultItemAnimator() );
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration( new MyDividerItemDecoration( this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, 16 ) );
        recyclerView.setAdapter( mAdapter );

        toggleEmptySeries();

        //On Long Click On The RecyclerView Item An Alert Dialog Is Opened With The Option To Choose Edit/Delete
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener( new RecyclerTouchListener( this, recyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, final int position) {

                int seriesId = seriesList.get( position ).getId();
                String seriesLeagueId = seriesList.get( position ).getLeagueId();
                String seriesBowlerId = seriesList.get( position ).getBowlerId();
                Intent myIntent = new Intent( SeriesActivity.this, GameActivity.class );
                myIntent.putExtra( "gameLeagueId", seriesLeagueId );
                myIntent.putExtra( "gameBowlerId", seriesBowlerId );
                myIntent.putExtra( "gameSeriesId", seriesId );
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 1);
                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
                showActionsDialog( position );
            }
        } ) );
    }


    //Inserting New Series In The Database And Refreshing The List
    private void createSeries(String leagueId, String bowlerId, String series) {
        //Inserting Series In The Database And Getting Newly Inserted Series Id
        long id = db.insertSeries( leagueId, bowlerId, series );

        //Get The Newly Inserted Series From The Database
        Series n = db.getSeries( leagueId, bowlerId );

        if (n != null) {
            //Adding New Series To The Array List At Position 0
            seriesList.add( 0, n );
            //Refreshing The List

            mAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged( db.getAllSeries( savedLeagueId, savedBowlerId ) );

            toggleEmptySeries();
        }
    }

    //Updating Series In The Database And Updating The Item In The List By Its Position
    private void updateSeries(String name, int position) {
        Series n = seriesList.get( position );

        //Updating Series Text
        n.setLeagueId( savedLeagueId );
        n.setBowlerId( savedBowlerId );
        n.setName( name );


        //Updating The Series In The Database
        db.updateSeries( n );

        //Refreshing The List
        seriesList.set( position, n );
        //mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
        mAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged( db.getAllSeries( savedLeagueId, savedBowlerId ) );


        toggleEmptySeries();
    }

    //Deleting Series From SQLite Database And Removing The Bowler Item From The List By Its Position
    private void deleteSeries(int position) {
        //Deleting The Series From The Database
        db.deleteSeries( seriesList.get( position ) );

        //Removing The Bowler From The List
        seriesList.remove( position );
        mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved( position );

        toggleEmptySeries();
    }

    //Opens Dialog With Edit/Delete Options
    //Edit - 0
    //Delete - 0
    private void showActionsDialog(final int position) {
        CharSequence colors[] = new CharSequence[]{"Edit", "Delete"};

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder( this );
        builder.setTitle( "Choose option" );
        builder.setItems( colors, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (which == 0) {
                    showSeriesDialog( true, seriesList.get( position ), position );
                } else {
                    deleteSeries( position );
                }
            }
        } );
        builder.show();
    }

    //Show Alert Dialog With EditText Options to Enter/Edit A Series
    //When shouldUpdate = true, It Will Automatically Display Old Series Name And Change The Button Text To UPDATE
    private void showSeriesDialog(final boolean shouldUpdate, final Series series, final int position) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflaterAndroid = LayoutInflater.from( getApplicationContext() );
        final View view = View.inflate( this, R.layout.dialog_series, null );

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilderUserInput = new AlertDialog.Builder( SeriesActivity.this );
        alertDialogBuilderUserInput.setView( view );

        final EditText inputSeries = view.findViewById( R.id.etSeriesNameInput );
        leagueId.setText( savedLeagueId );
        bowlerId.setText( savedBowlerId );
        TextView dialogTitle = view.findViewById( R.id.dialog_title );
        dialogTitle.setText( !shouldUpdate ? getString( R.string.lbl_new_series_title ) : getString( R.string.lbl_edit_series_title ) );

        if (shouldUpdate && series != null) {
            inputSeries.setText( series.getName() );
            leagueId.setText( series.getLeagueId() );
            bowlerId.setText( series.getBowlerId() );

        }
        alertDialogBuilderUserInput.setCancelable( false ).setPositiveButton( shouldUpdate ? "update" : "save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogBox, int id) {

            }
        } ).setNegativeButton( "cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogBox, int id) {
                dialogBox.cancel();
            }
        } ) .setNeutralButton("use date",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogBox, int id) {
                        String dateNow = getDateNow();
                        inputSeries.setText(dateNow);

                    }
                });

        final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilderUserInput.create();
        alertDialog.show();

        alertDialog.getButton( AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL ).setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //Show Toast Message When No Text Is Entered
                if (inputSeries.getText().toString() !=null || !inputSeries.getText().toString().isEmpty() ) {
                    String dateNow = getDateNow();
                    inputSeries.setText(dateNow);
                    return;
                } else {
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                }


                //Check If User Is Updating Series
                if (shouldUpdate && series != null) {

                    //Updating Series By Its Id
                    updateSeries( inputSeries.getText().toString(), position );

                } else {
                    //Creating New Series
                    createSeries( leagueId.getText().toString(), bowlerId.getText().toString(), inputSeries.getText().toString() );
                }
            }
        } );


        alertDialog.getButton( AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE ).setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 //Show Toast Message When No Text Is Entered
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty( inputSeries.getText().toString() )) {
                    Toast.makeText( SeriesActivity.this, "Enter Series!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                    return;
                } else {
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                }


                //Check If User Is Updating Series
                if (shouldUpdate && series != null) {

                    //Updating Series By Its Id
                    updateSeries( inputSeries.getText().toString(), position );

                } else {
                    //Creating New Series
                    createSeries( leagueId.getText().toString(), bowlerId.getText().toString(), inputSeries.getText().toString() );
                }
            }
        } );
    }

    //Toggling List And Empty Series View
    private void toggleEmptySeries() {
        //You Can Check seriesList.size() > 0

        if (db.getSeriesCount() > 0) {
            noSeriesView.setVisibility( View.GONE );
        } else {
            noSeriesView.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate( R.menu.menu_main, menu );
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected( item );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        //Check If Request Code Is The Same As What Is Passed - Here It Is 1
        if(requestCode==1)
        {
            String savedLeagueId=data.getStringExtra("seriesLeagueId");
            String savedBowlerId=data.getStringExtra("seriesBowlerId");
            seriesList.addAll( db.getAllSeries( savedLeagueId, savedBowlerId ) );
        }
    }

    private String getDateNow() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE. MMM. dd, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        return sdf.format(cal.getTime());
    }
    @Override protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume(); //seriesList.addAll( db.getAllSeries( savedLeagueId, savedBowlerId) );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the values to be written in the db you must call:

```
values.put(Series.COLUMN_SERIES_AVERAGE, total); 
update(table_name, values, "column_name=column_value", null)
```

`table_name` is the name of the table where you insert the `values`

Comment: No, replace table_name with the name of the table inside "" like "mytable" and call it as it is written above

Comment: If you want the id of the new row created I edited the answer

Comment: Why do you use series.getAverage() and not total?

Comment: I am still seeing the same results in Logcat: `07-26 15:33:22.320 27212-27212/ca.rvogl.tpbcui D/TOTAL - CURSOR VALUE: Total = >>>>207<<<<
07-26 15:33:22.359 27212-27212/ca.rvogl.tpbcui D/SERIES_AVERAGE - SQL: COLUMN_SERIES_AVERAGE = >>>>average<<<<`

Comment: Use another one: `Log.d("ID=", id + "");` just right after insert. If it prints -1 then the row can't be added

Comment: `7-26 15:49:54.448 28120-28120/ca.rvogl.tpbcui D/GETALLSERIES-SQL: SQL used = >>>>SELECT  * FROM Series WHERE league_id = '1' AND bowler_id = '1' ORDER BY timestamp DESC<<<<
07-26 15:49:54.466 28120-28120/ca.rvogl.tpbcui D/GETALLSERIESS-CNT: Number of rows retrieved = 1
07-26 15:49:54.515 28120-28120/ca.rvogl.tpbcui D/ID =: 4
07-26 15:49:54.516 28120-28120/ca.rvogl.tpbcui D/SERIES_AVERAGE - SQL: COLUMN_SERIES_AVERAGE = >>>>average<<<<
07-26 15:49:54.517 28120-28120/ca.rvogl.tpbcui D/TOTAL - CURSOR VALUE: Total = >>>>111<<<<'

Comment: I have noticed that the id keeps increasing.  I don't want to write the average to a new row.  I want to be able to write it to the row that the average came from for example League = 1, Bowler = 1,  when I go to the listview in the SeriesActivity I want to be able to see the average score for each series that is assigned to League = 1 and Bowler = 1.  There could be 1 series or ten or more.  I am pretty sure that my whole approach to this is probably wrong.

Comment: So you have a table "Series" which has a column named Series.COLUMN_SERIES_AVERAGE (I don't know the real name of the column), is it the only column? Because if there are others that are declared NOT NULL then the row can't be inserted. Execute the log I proposed in my previous comment to see if the row is added

Comment: This is a totally different situation

Comment: I realize that. Now that I have been trying to get this to work.  But yes there other columns in the table.  I.e. series_name, series_datetimestamp.

Comment: You must post the whole table structure with column names, which column you want to be updated and by which column to be found

Comment: So based on you change to your answer, I have posted a revised method.  I am now storing 1 of the averages to the listview.  However the name of the series has disappeared and I believe that this is due to not posting the table structure as you mentioned in your last update.  I have also posted a screen-shot of what I am currently seeing and the logcat

Comment: The question is how do I get the next id in the series to write the next average to the table.  The id's could be **First Series (id 1) / Second Series (id 10) / Third Series (id 11)** and so forth. So adding one to the id is not valid method of getting to the next valid Id Number.

Comment: I have this working, the average is just not refreshing when I go back to the SeriesActivity.  I have to go back two activities and then go into the SeriesActivity to see the updated Average.

Comment: When your activity regains focus the `onResume()` method is called:     `@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        
        // your code
    }`

Comment: I added the onResume() to the bottom of my Activity and called it after the onCreate(), but the SeriesActivity still doesn't refresh when returning into the SeriesActivity.  I tried putting my code for retrieving the list view in the onResume() as well. But it simply duplicated the list view.  I have posted my SeriesActivity above.

Comment: You don't call the onResume method. It must be overriden(with the Override annotation on top):  `@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    // put your code here...

}`

Comment: Now I saw what you did. If you want it this way you must clear the list first and then add all the items

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help, This function is working perfectly now.

Comment: I'm glad. Be well